# Summation with out limit

Tags: summation

Can someone explain me how I read that sum notation?
I have that task:
$$n\in \mathbb{N}^* \quad and \quad A_1...A_n \quad are\ finite\ groups  $$
$$
    \#(\cup_{i=1} ^{n} A_i)=\sum_{I \subseteq[n], I\neq \emptyset}(-1)^{( \#I)}\#( \cap_{i\in I}A_i)
$$
The thing that i don't understand is how to read it when the sum doesn't have limit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle

Comment: What does # signify in the expression?

Comment: The sum ranges over all non-empty sets $I$, which are a subset of $[n]$

Comment: # means the cardinality